# How to place an image into header.php?

Tags: images, headers

I'm trying to customize twentyten theme.
this is part of header.php:

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="wrapper" class="hfeed">
    <div id="header">

<img id="topL" src="images/img01.png"/> //this img I cannot insert  !   

</div><!-- #header -->
```

No errors. Simply - nothing happens.

Comment: Is there a public URL?

Comment: @s_ha_dum, no, it's on my localhost :(

Comment: @toscho, Firebug shows all divs normally, including `header` div which is the parent div of the image, but there is no image inside, and there is no error.

Comment: Look at the real source, not at the rendered JS DOM.

Comment: @toscho, important, Firebug shows my starting code version - i. e. `<img id="topL" src="/images/img01.png">`

Comment: So your image is missing. Download and install my [404 tools](https://github.com/toscho/T5-404-Tools), you should get a red image then. Follow @s_ha_dum’s answer, and look into your server error log to see what file the browser is trying to load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a relative URL. If you look at the source you are probably trying to load the image from `http://sitename.com/images/` when what you likely want is `http://sitename.com/wp-content/themes/themename/images/`. Assuming the image is in the theme directory in a folder that shares a directory with `style.css`, do this:

```
<img id="topL" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/img01.png"/>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

Comment: s_ha_dum, `the image is in the theme directory in a folder that shares a directory with style.css`, yes it is, and I placed your code - and again - nothing !

Comment: I believe that should be `echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri();`

Comment: You are correct, @bungeshea.